# Redirect all HTTP/HTTPS traffic through WireGuard to external HTTP Proxy

Tags: iptables, firewall, routing, wireguard, http-proxy

I have set up a Wireguard VPN whereby all of my devices connect to a Wireguard peer running on a computer with a public IP address (host).

My Wireguard is set up so that clients connect to the host on wg0, which uses the subnet 10.10.0.1/24. The clients can access other services running in the LAN (e.g. web servers running at 192.168.1.100) and also other services running on the internet (e.g. Google.com).

wg0.conf

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.10.0.1/24
ListenPort = 51823
PrivateKey = XXXXXX
```

client.conf

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = XXXXXX
Address = 10.10.0.2/32
DNS = 1.1.1.1

[Peer]
PublicKey = XXXXXX
PresharedKey = XXXXXX
Endpoint = 1.2.3.4:51823
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
```

With this setup, when I check the IP address, it shows the public IP address of the Wireguard server.

I want to add an external HTTP / HTTPS proxy in the middle of this, which sits between all traffic on port 80 / 443 which is going outside of the LAN network.

The overview of what I want to achieve is:

```
<---------- 10.10.0.1/24 ------------><------------- internet ---------------->

                     192.168.1.1
10.10.0.2             10.10.0.1             13.14.15.16
----------            --------               ---------        -----------------
| client |---tunnel---| host |----http(s)----| proxy |--------| anydomain.com |
----------            -------- \              ---------      /-----------------
                          |     \                           /
                          |      \------ non-http(s) ------/
                          |
                         lan
                    192.168.1.0/24
                          |
                          |
                          |
                   ---------------   
                   | http server |
                   | 192.168.1.2 |
                   ---------------
```

I tried using `iptables` to forwards all traffic on port 80 and 443 to the proxy server, however the proxy server responds with an error "The requested URL could not be retrieved".

How do I forward all traffic on port 80 and 443 to this external proxy server?

--

The `iptables` rules I tried are:

```
# enable ip forwarding
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

# allow traffic on 51823
iptables -I INPUT -p udp --dport 51823 -j ACCEPT

# forward traffic on eth0 to wgo
iptables -I FORWARD -i eth0 -o wg0 -j ACCEPT

# allow traffic on wg0
iptables -I FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT

# route outgoing traffic on eth0
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

# route all http/https traffic to proxy
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp –dport 80 -j DNAT –to-destination 13.14.15.16:8888
```

Comment: Did you configure the proxy appropriately for intercepted traffic?

Comment: iptables pre routing looks OK imho

Comment: First thing you really should do is to actually block all outgoing traffic over ports TCP 80 and TCP 443 at **host**. Second thing is to configure **host** to use a proxy server.